# Some questions about Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, signal-processing

I have some questions about Hilbert transform when I read Real Analysis:

1. In Stein "Real Analysis" p.220, the Hilbert transform is defined by $P=\frac{I+iH}{2}$, where $P$ is an orthogonal projection on the subspace $S$ of $L^{2}$. But to my knowledge, the Hilbert transform of a function $f(x)$ is defined to be the convolution of $f(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\pi x}$ in signal processing. I cannot figure out the connection of these two definitions.
2. In p.221, it mentions "Among the many important properties of Hilbert transform is its connection to conjugate harmonic functions. Indeed, for $f $ a real-valued function in $L^{2}(R)$, $f$ and $H(f)$ are, respectively, the real and imaginary parts of the boundary values of a function in the Hardy space.". Would anyone know where is this result from?

Comment: $P$ is not the Hilbert transform, but the analytic signal.  $H$ is the Hilbert transform. $H$ multiplies the FT by $-i \ sign(\omega)$ while $P$ multiplies it by $\frac{1+ sign(\omega)}{2} = 1_{\omega > 0}$  and hence is an orthogonal projection operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform

Comment: I know that in this definition H is the Hilbert transform, i just can't understand why this definition is equivalent to the convolution of $f(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\pi x}$

Comment: wikipedia..  $  $

Answer (score 0):

I just know a similar conclusion. In Loukas Grafakos's book *Classical Fourier Analysis*, he prove that, for function $\varphi$ in $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$, we have
$$
F_{\varphi}(z)=\cfrac i\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cfrac{\varphi(t)}{z-t}\mathrm dt \to \varphi(x)+iH(\varphi)(x).
$$
And he given a proof that extends $H(f)$ from $\mathcal S$ to $L^p$. When $p\gt1$, we know that $H^p=L^p$. I hope this can help you.